# Day to day practice

Tags: mindfulness

Strong  headache dissolved with little  time of meditation. Previous experience was differ from  this,when this type of headache experienced it wasn't dissolved by practiced meditation. And happiness slowly invading while headache dissolving. Insight came it as anatta. Is it true anatta?

Comment: Who experienced this insight of anatta?

Answer (score 1):

Observing the headache truly:

> [MN62:8.5](https://suttacentral.net/mn62/en/sujato#mn62:8.5): This should be truly seen with right understanding like this: ‘This is not mine, I am not this, this is not my self.’

Observing the happiness truly:

> [MN62:8.5](https://suttacentral.net/mn62/en/sujato#mn62:8.5): This should be truly seen with right understanding like this: ‘This is not mine, I am not this, this is not my self.’

How can the impermanent be true?

> [SN12.61:4.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.61/en/sujato#sn12.61:4.1): But that which is called ‘mind’ or ‘sentience’ or ‘consciousness’ arises as one thing and ceases as another all day and all night.

The truth satisfies. Chasing selves and not-selves does not satisfy.

> [SN35.164:1.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.164/en/sujato#sn35.164:1.3): “Yo kho, koṭṭhika, ***anattā*** tatra te chando pahātabbo.

> [SN35.164:1.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.164/en/sujato#sn35.164:1.3): “Koṭṭhita, you should give up desire for what is not-self.